# HighCharts Render Annotated Queryset in Jinja2 Template

Tags: python, django, highcharts, django-orm

In my `Jinja2` template I want to render a `JavaScript` array similar to this:

```
[{
    name: 'test',
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(1970, 9, 29), 0],
        [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 9), 0.4],
        ...
    ]
},
{
    name: 'Transport',
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 25), 0],
        ...
    ]
}]
```

I already managed to build a rather *complex* queryset in my `Django` code. It looks like the following:

```
(Category.objects.filter(expense__period=p)
    .annotate(day=Trunc('expense__date', 'day'))
    .values('title', 'day')
    .order_by('title', 'day')
    .annotate(Sum('expense__amount'), Count('id')))
```

Which results in:

```
TITLE       DAY                         EXPENSE__AMOUNT__SUM    ID__COUNT
test        2017-12-30 00:00:00+00:00   10.00                   1
test        2018-01-08 00:00:00+00:00   2.70                    1
test        2018-01-09 00:00:00+00:00   62.00                   2
Transport   2018-01-03 00:00:00+00:00   111.00                  1
Transport   2018-01-09 00:00:00+00:00   15.00                   1
Transport   2018-01-10 00:00:00+00:00   12.00                   1
```

I am stuck at this point and look for a performant way to apply the retrieved data to my template. Any idea how to break the rows into categories/loop over the results without querying the database multiple times?

---

My `models.py` is:

```
class Period(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Expense(models.Model):
    period = models.ForeignKey(Period, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True)
    amount = MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default_currency='EUR')
```

---

*Edit*:
I coincidentally found the [default template tag `regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) which could be useful in this scenario. *In the next days, I will try to take a deeper look at the problem since I am currently working on a different project.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated: The [`regroup` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) is the tool of choice. Don't forget that the queryset has to be ordered.

```
{% regroup queryset by title as categories %}

{% for category in categories %}
    {
        name: '{{ category.grouper }}',
        data: [
            {% for expense in category.list %}
                [{% widthratio expense.day|date:"U" 1 1000 %}, {{ expense.expense__amount__sum }}],
            {% endfor %}
        ]
    },
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Note however that `regroup` is a Django template tag, and not part of Jinja2, as your question states. Jinja2 has its own grouping mechanism, incorporated into the `for` tag syntax.